# Public and Private Key in RSA Algorithm Cryptography Number Theory

Tags: number-theory, algorithms, cryptography, euclidean-algorithm

Anyone know about RSA Algorithm? If you don't, I will explain it. So to get a public and private key in RSA we need two primes number, let $p$ and $q$ be two prime number then we count $n=p.q$ and $\varphi (n)=(p-1)(q-1)$, next we choose public key e which prime relative with $\varphi (n)$, that is $gcd(e,\varphi(n))=1$, and $1<e<\varphi (n)$, next we find private key d which satisfied $e.d \equiv 1\pmod{\varphi (n)}$, example we have $p=7, q=11$ so that $\varphi (n)=60$, then we choose $e=13$, and finally we find $d=37$ and can't be another number.

**Question**: The question is for every different $e$ then $i$ get different $d$ or the value of is unique, is that true? If yes how can $i$ prove it mathematically? Let say $i$ want to prove for every different value of e, the value of d is also different or d is unique? The idea that $i$ have is using contraposition let $e_1.d=e_2.d$ then $e_1=e_2$, anyone can help me to prove that? If you have another method you can use it as long as it true. Thank you.

Comment: $d$ isn't even unique given a fixed $e$.  See wikipedia.

Comment: How to prove that? Can you give me the link of that wikipedia?

Comment: Please don't duplicate your [prior question(s)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4066734/242)

Comment: It's literally in the wiki article on RSA.

Comment: To be fair, the question here is not about uniqueness of inverses in a given modulus.  While it is true that there is a unique $d$ satisfying $ed \equiv 1 \bmod \varphi(n)$ in RSA (because inverses $\bmod \varphi(n)$ are indeed unique), there are in fact multiple valid values of $d \bmod \varphi(n)$ that act as faithful decryption exponents for $e$.  This is due to the differences between $\varphi(n)$ and the Carmichael function $\lambda(n)$.

Comment: Thank you everyone:-)